# Find an example of a function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ that is non bounded and nowhere continuous.

Tags: real-analysis

We have to find an example of a function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ that is non bounded and nowhere continuous.

My try:I think its "Dirchilet discontinuous " function.Plz check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about 
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
1+|x|, & x\ne \Bbb Q\\
0, & x\in\Bbb Q 
\end{cases}$$
?

Comment: sir,I understood that its discontinuous but how can we see unbounded?

Comment: @MatheMagic what is your definition of boundedness? I assume you mean "unbounded on $\Bbb R$". So given any $G>0$ just find an irrational $x>G$ and then $f(x)=G+1>G$.

Comment: @MatheMagic but you want a nowhere discontinuous function don't you? The function you give is continuous everywhere except at $x=0$.

Comment: ok.I understood.Thanks a lot